# Como colocar uma imagem em um botão HTML

Tags: css, html5, asp.net-mvc-5, background-image

Estou criando um botão em uma determinada pagina e gostaria de colocar uma imagem de fundo.

Estou tentando utilizar a tag `background-image:url()` no CSS porém não esta funcionando.

HTML:

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.Comercial.ComercialModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<div id="Open_menu">
    <span onclick="openNav()">Menu</span>
</div>

<h2>Comercial</h2>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "MenuInicial")</a>
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Serviços", "Index", "Servicos")</a>
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Comercial", "Index", "Comercial")</a>
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Estoque", "Index", "Estoque")</a>
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Equipamentos", "Index", "Equipamentos")</a>
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Compras", "Index", "Compras")</a>
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Fiscal", "Index", "Fiscal")</a>
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Caixa", "Index", "Caixa")</a>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" class="but_clientes">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*botao abrir menu lateral*/

#Open_menu {
    position: fixed;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: 350px;
    font-size: 20px;
    transform: rotate(270deg)
}

.but_clientes {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image:url('C:\clientes.png');
    border: groove
}
```

Tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Hierarquia do projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atualização, Foi criado uma pasta no projeto chamada `Image` porem mesmo assim, não funcionou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Me mande a hierarquia do projeto. Onde fica o html e o css.

Comment: Fiz uma revisão.

Comment: ficheiros nao podem ser servidos através de c:\ -- tens que usar um servidor e servir os ficheiros apartir dessa pasta, qq coisa como `images/imagem.png`

Comment: Criei uma pasta chamada image, e mesmo assim não foi, fiz uma revisão na pergunta

Comment: @MoshMage deu certo, eu estava digitando o caminho errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso de um website, os ficheiros não podem ser servidos do teu sistema local. Primeiro, porque o sistema onde o site estará alojado não terá (certamente) o mesmo sistema que o seu (pode, por ex, nao existir `c:\`). Segundo porque, no caso de estares a fazer uma aplicação que queres que só corra no teu browser em tua casa, é um sistema de segurança nos novos browsers.

Para ficar certo, tens que criar uma pasta no teu projecto que será servido pelo servidor, por exemplo `Images`, e apontar as imagens para aí. ex: `background-image:url(Images/image.ext)`

Se, no entanto, queres a segunda opção e não tens um servidor a servir o `index.html` tens que ir procurar qual é a flag do browser que usas; Fazer um novo atalho para o browser e nos parametros de chamada incluir essa mesma flag. No caso do chrome, é `--allow-file-access-from-files.`

Answer (score 4):

Tenta assim :

```html
<input type="image" src="http://www.drpeppersnapplegroup.com/smedia/www/2013/04/17/img-volunteer-button_163957695590.jpg" alt="Submit" width="110" height="40">
```